# Reading long / lat from sql geography point

Tags: sql, sql-server, geography

I have added a new column to my locations database table called `geo_loc`.

I have run the script convert the values in the long / lat columns to create the geography point for each set of long / lat

The geography column in the table now displays the value  ?? Not sure how I get to see the actual contents of the geography column.

Also when I try and run the code to read the long / lat values from the geography column eg

```
select geo_loc.lat 
from locations
```

SQL Server generates an error message

> column not find the lat value in the geography assembly

If anyone can shed some light on the above I would be very grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the geospatial data types are implemented as CLR, the method names (like Lat) are case sensitive. So, you need to use `geo_loc.Lat` and `geo_loc.Long`.

Comment: Yes indeed thanks that work

however i am a little confused about the results it seems the co ordinates retrieved from the geo_location field of geography column type is not showing all the decimal places that are recorded in the actual co ordinates

The co ordinates extracted from the geography column:

-31.9095 115.81 

The actual co ordinates  -31.9094567 115.810405

Comment: I don't know how you created your points, but when I create a Point with the coordinates you specify, I get back all of the places after the decimal point. `declare @g geography

set @g = geography::Point( -31.9094567, 115.810405, 4326);

select @g.Lat, @g.Long;`